# Strange destructuring assignment, giving undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, lodash

```
const apiConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.apiConfig);
const securityContextConfigurations = _.get(
  apiConfig,
  'agpAPIs',
  {});

/// what is going here?

const {
  securityContext : { apiKey, securityType }
} = securityContextConfigurations;

/// end what is going on here?
/// securityContext always comes back as undefined even though there is data in the securityContextConfigurations object

const securityContext = { apiKey, securityType };
const { serviceContext } = apiConfig;
serviceContext.refID = v5(serviceContext.refID, v1());
return Promise.resolve({ securityContext, serviceContext });
```

`securityContextConfigurations` is an object and the key value pairs that i'm looking for are located in the `securityContextConfigurations` object, but my code always fails on that specific `const` where I'm trying to create the object for `securityContext`

I've never seen a pattern like this, and I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify it.

Comment: You should provide an example of the config so we can debug it.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to ask that. let me make it ambiguous .. one moment.

I'm more interested in what that type of pattern is, and what it's supposed to do. I'm slightly confused.

Comment: I have amended the title to make it clearer what you want readers to focus on. I think that is why it got downvotes from other people.

Comment: Thanks Eureka! I had NO idea how to ask this question and you've cleared it up wonderfully for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's a complex form of destructuring assignment

You are probably familiar with this simpler type.

```js
const a={b:3, c:"hello"}

const {b, c} = a

console.log("b is ",b)
console.log("c is ",c)
```

Here they are simply doing an extra level of it.

```js
const securityContextConfigurations = {
  securityContext: {
    apiKey: "hello",
    securityType: "high"
  }
}

const {
  securityContext: {
    apiKey,   
    securityType
  }
} = securityContextConfigurations;

// The innermost items are extracted as variables

console.log("apiKey is", apiKey)
console.log("securityType is", securityType)
// However "securityContext" is not extracted as a variable
```

Remember that in JS {a, b} is shorthand for {a:a, b:b}. To explore what is happening, we can put different variable names on the two sides of the ":".

```js
const securityContextConfigurations = {
  securityContext: {
    apiKey: "hello",
    securityType: "high"
  }
}

const {
  securityContext: {
    apiKey:x,   
    securityType:y
  }
} = securityContextConfigurations;

// The destination variable name on the *right hand side* of the ":". The variable name on the left of the ":" is only to tell JS which element of the source to extract.  

console.log("x is", x)
console.log("y is", y)

// apiKey, securityType and securityContext are not extracted as variabels.
```

If it is any consolation, I have been coding in JS for over a decade and I have never seen it before, either. 8-)

#### What the programmer was probably doing

For reasons best known to them, they wanted to extract the smaller elements and then reassemble them into the bigger object `securityContext`.

So the code you highlighted gets *only* `apiKey` and `securityType`.

The line after that reconstructs a new object `securityContext` which contains those elements.

Normally you and I would probably just get `securityContext` directly, and then extract the elements `securityType` and `apiKey`.

Maybe the author was trying to *avoid* getting any other parts of `securityContext` other than those two? That is why they chose to extract them first, and then reassemble a new `securityContext` that only had the desired items.

#### How one could re-write it to make it easier to understand

```js
const apiKey = securityContextConfigurations.apiKey
const securityType = securityContextConfigurations.securityType
const securityContext = { apiKey, securityType };
```